# Twilio Flex - How Do I View My Call Logs / Records?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

I have an IVR application built on top of Twilio Studio / Flex.  At the end of my Studio flow, I send the user to a Flex agent.

How would I get a log of all calls that were sent to Flex?  I am looking for the start time (when a call was answered by an agent in Flex), the end time (when an answered call ends), the number the call came from, and the attributes that were passed to Flex for that call from Studio.

Also, is there a way to make a request to a webhook after each call to pass this info to an endpoint that I control?